# Recommendations front end framework for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

In an effort to standardize developments where I work I would like opinions on the best front end framework to use.

Currently our websites are all built with ASP.net web forms.  I'd like the potential to develop using MVC going forward although this wont be a quick change.  We currently have a horrible mix of asp ajax / jquery / telerik / various other 3rd party controls / bootstrap.

Started to use Bootstrap recently which seems to be quite favorable within the team although I'm not sure this is necessarily the best approach when integrating with .net.

Opinions / guidance welcome.

Comment: This is opinion based and is off topic for the site.

Comment: nothing wrong with using bootstrap with mvc, the separation of concerns with the mvc pattern make it easy to work with whatever you want on the view side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is the default UI Framework in the [Visual Studio 2013 web project templates](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#bootstrap).

It integrates tightly with Asp.Net MVC. With Asp.Net MVC 5.1 you even get [Bootstrap support for editor templates](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Bootstrap). So I would consider Bootstrap a good choice.

If you pick another framework you have to remove the default UI Framework (Bootstrap) from the solution and follow the instructions for the specific framework. Usually not a big deal.

A competitor for Bootstrap is the [Foundation Framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/). You find a step by step tutorial how to integrate it with Asp.net [here](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/zurb-foundation-4-with-asp-net-mvc-5). You could take this as a blueprint how to integrate other frameworks.

Remember we are just talking Front-End Framework. If you are concerned about your Presentation Layer Technologies I recommend reading through the free Microsoft [NET Technology Guide for Business Applications](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/E/16E9FC39-0D61-4DB8-AADE-9F6950B8BF49/Microsoft_Press_eBook_NET_Technology_Guide_for_Business_Applications.pdf) ebook.